# Image field with sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I am using sencha touch to make a form.fieldset. In my model I have an image field, how can i do to display the current image of my model? My form.fieldset looks like :

```
/**
 * This is used by the NestedList example to allow editing of an item in the Store
 */
Ext.define('ParkingSencha.view.EditorPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet'],
    id: 'editorPanel',
    config: {
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: false,
        centered: true,
        width: 500,
        scrollable: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'keyword',
                label: 'Mots clés'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'title',
                label: 'Titre'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'image',
                label: 'image'
            }
            ]
          }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want your image to be loaded in your third textfield area?

Comment: Yes i want to load it in the third textfield. My images are stored on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *using / loading* the `image` in a `formfield`, you need to use `image` component, not `textfield`.

Do it like this,

```
....
{
  xtype: 'image',
  src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
  flex: 1
},
....
```

Comment: Image inside a textfield? How can that make any sense?

Comment: When you edit a model with an image. You want to show the current image right? That's what i want to do. I wrote textfield just because i didn't know what to use.

Comment: Image component is used for image in ST, not textfield.

Comment: I know, do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

**There is another solution for this take a label and set a image inside html tag ....:)
like this**

```
{
xtype:'label',
html:'<img src="path of image ">'
}
```

or the boomslang ans is more than correct i will recommend you to use that ..